# "That’s what I have done" VS "That’s what I did."

Tags: expressions

> A: Let's implement a feature:......
>
> B: #1)That's what I have done
>
> B: #2)That's what I did.

Which do you prefer? Originally, I use #1, but someone told me that #2 is more proper.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9532/done-vs-have-done I found this useful thread.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because more detail is needed to answer the question.  Both are acceptable, but which you use may vary with context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The trickiest use** of present perfect versus simple past is this one:

Sometimes, a speaker merely wants to say something happened in the past and **when specifically it happened is not relevant**. Present perfect can be used this way. However, **this use also implies that the statement that is made is true at the time the speaker says it. In that sense, it is the same with all uses of the present perfect**.

- I have gone to the theater in the past.

Other times, a speaker wants to specifically say a thing happened in the past, and it implies a temporal identifier such as: last week, yesterday, two days ago. And this is true even if the speaker does not specifically provide a time. Or, of course, that the action is no longer true at the time of speaking.

- I didn't go to the theater. [implied: a specific time: last week, yesterday, earlier today, last night].

So, you have to decide what you want to say. Both are grammatical. Which one you use is not dictated by grammar. It is dictated by what you wish to express and the larger context of what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

**That's what I've done** could be considered the more polite of the two responses.  It could be taken to mean "you and I are on the same page there", whereas **That's what I did** could be taken to mean "I'm a step ahead of you there" or "Tell me something I don't already know".

But these would be faint nuances.